# Deserializer failing when running in Graal

Tags: java, jackson, micronaut, graalvm, graalvm-native-image

I have a Micronaut application that builds into a GraalVM native image. When I run the application from a normal standpoint (i.e. no Graal) it runs perfectly.

However when I try to run from Graal I get the following runtime exception when trying to deserialize a String into an enum:

```
org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SerializationException: Error deserializing key/value for partition queue.mes.tm_email_processing_result-0 at offset 57. If needed, please seek past the record to continue consumption.
Caused by: io.micronaut.core.serialize.exceptions.SerializationException: Error deserializing object from JSON: Class fts.marketing.utils.deserializers.CampaignEmailStatusDeserializer has no default (no arg) constructor
 at [Source: (byte[])"{"merchant":"Lab6","customerId":729441,"campaignRunId":51,"status":"Sent","messageKey":"70bb5454-8e22-4b37-bba7-83c0dd0cb66f"}"; line: 1, column: 1]
    at io.micronaut.jackson.serialize.JacksonObjectSerializer.deserialize(JacksonObjectSerializer.java:70)
    at io.micronaut.configuration.kafka.serde.JsonSerde.deserialize(JsonSerde.java:79)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Deserializer.deserialize(Deserializer.java:60)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.Fetcher.parseRecord(Fetcher.java:1264)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.Fetcher.access$3600(Fetcher.java:124)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.Fetcher$PartitionRecords.fetchRecords(Fetcher.java:1488)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.Fetcher$PartitionRecords.access$1600(Fetcher.java:1328)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.Fetcher.fetchRecords(Fetcher.java:641)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.Fetcher.fetchedRecords(Fetcher.java:602)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.pollForFetches(KafkaConsumer.java:1294)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.poll(KafkaConsumer.java:1225)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.poll(KafkaConsumer.java:1201)
    at io.micronaut.configuration.kafka.processor.KafkaConsumerProcessor.lambda$process$7(KafkaConsumerProcessor.java:393)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
    at com.oracle.svm.core.thread.JavaThreads.threadStartRoutine(JavaThreads.java:460)
    at com.oracle.svm.core.posix.thread.PosixJavaThreads.pthreadStartRoutine(PosixJavaThreads.java:193)
```

For reference my deserializer is the following:

```
public class CampaignEmailStatusDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<CampaignEmailStatus> {

    @Override
    public CampaignEmailStatus deserialize(JsonParser p, DeserializationContext ctxt) throws IOException {
        String readValue = p.getText();
        if (readValue == null) {
            return CampaignEmailStatus.UNKNOWN;
    }

        return Arrays.stream(CampaignEmailStatus.values())
        .filter(status -> status.getDisplayName().equals(readValue))
        .findAny()
        .orElse(CampaignEmailStatus.UNKNOWN);
    }

}
```

I think that I might need to add some custom reflection configuration for Graal but I'm not really sure. Can anyone shed some light here?

Comment: May be you can read your error message `Class fts.marketing.utils.deserializers.CampaignEmailStatusDeserializer has no default (no arg) constructor` and add an constructor in your `CampaignEmailStatusDeserializer.class`

Comment: @Zorglube are you saying this out of experience working with Graal or just by reciting the error message?

Comment: @aris-kortex this is out of reading the message, the VM is telling you it's need an default constructor with zero argument : so it seems you should try to add an zero args contructor in your object. Have you tryed ?

Answer (score 4):

After a bit of digging it seems that the problem was attributed from a reflective call that was being disallowed by SubtrateVM.

I added a configuration file for reflective calls containing the following entry:

```
{
    "name": "fts.marketing.utils.deserializers.CampaignEmailStatusDeserializer",
    "allDeclaredConstructors" : true,
    "allPublicConstructors" : true,
    "allDeclaredMethods" : true,
    "allPublicMethods" : true,
    "allDeclaredClasses" : true,
    "allPublicClasses" : true
  }
```

and configured the native image to use this resolved all issues.