spring native kafka.common.KafkaException: Could not find a public no-argument constructor for io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaJsonSerializer

Include details about your goal

Run a SpringBoot 3.2.4 reactor kafka producer with graalVM 21 native image.

Describe expected results

A simple SpringBoot reactor kafka producer project is working fine as non native image. The image has been built many times, running with low, high load without any issue.
Now, I am trying to convert the job into a native image.
I expect the same process to also build, run fine.

Describe actual results:

While the build of the native image is happening without issue, at runtime, it seems there is an issue specific to graalVM native image.
The error stack trace is:
reactor.core.Exceptions$ErrorCallbackNotImplemented: org.apache.kafka.common.KafkaException: Failed to construct kafka producer
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.KafkaException: Failed to construct kafka producer
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer.<init>(KafkaProducer.java:459)
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer.<init>(KafkaProducer.java:287)
        at reactor.kafka.sender.internals.ProducerFactory.createProducer(ProducerFactory.java:34)
        at reactor.kafka.sender.internals.DefaultKafkaSender.lambda$new$2(DefaultKafkaSender.java:102)
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoCallable.call(MonoCallable.java:72)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxSubscribeOnCallable$CallableSubscribeOnSubscription.run(FluxSubscribeOnCallable.java:228)
        at reactor.core.scheduler.ImmediateScheduler.schedule(ImmediateScheduler.java:52)
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoSubscribeOnCallable.subscribe(MonoSubscribeOnCallable.java:52)
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoCacheTime.subscribeOrReturn(MonoCacheTime.java:143)
        at reactor.core.publisher.Flux.subscribe(Flux.java:8825)
        at reactor.core.publisher.Flux.subscribeWith(Flux.java:8961)
        at reactor.core.publisher.Flux.subscribe(Flux.java:8805)
        at reactor.core.publisher.Flux.subscribe(Flux.java:8729)
        at reactor.core.publisher.Flux.subscribe(Flux.java:8647)
        at com.Service.run(Service.java:51)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.lambda$callRunner$5(SpringApplication.java:790)
        at org.springframework.util.function.ThrowingConsumer$1.acceptWithException(ThrowingConsumer.java:83)
        at org.springframework.util.function.ThrowingConsumer.accept(ThrowingConsumer.java:60)
        at org.springframework.util.function.ThrowingConsumer$1.accept(ThrowingConsumer.java:88)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:798)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:789)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.lambda$callRunners$3(SpringApplication.java:774)
        at java.base@21.0.2/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.accept(ForEachOps.java:184)
        at java.base@21.0.2/java.util.stream.SortedOps$SizedRefSortingSink.end(SortedOps.java:357)
        at java.base@21.0.2/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:510)
        at java.base@21.0.2/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:499)
        at java.base@21.0.2/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:151)
        at java.base@21.0.2/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:174)
        at java.base@21.0.2/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
        at java.base@21.0.2/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:596)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunners(SpringApplication.java:774)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:341)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1354)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1343)
        at com.Application.main(Application.java:18)
        at java.base@21.0.2/java.lang.invoke.LambdaForm$DMH/sa346b79c.invokeStaticInit(LambdaForm$DMH)
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.KafkaException: Could not find a public no-argument constructor for io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaJsonSerializer
        at org.apache.kafka.common.utils.Utils.newInstance(Utils.java:399)
        at org.apache.kafka.common.config.AbstractConfig.getConfiguredInstance(AbstractConfig.java:395)
        at org.apache.kafka.common.config.AbstractConfig.getConfiguredInstance(AbstractConfig.java:434)
        at org.apache.kafka.common.config.AbstractConfig.getConfiguredInstance(AbstractConfig.java:419)
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer.<init>(KafkaProducer.java:385)
        ... 35 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaJsonSerializer.<init>()
        at java.base@21.0.2/java.lang.Class.checkMethod(DynamicHub.java:1075)
        at java.base@21.0.2/java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(DynamicHub.java:1238)
        at java.base@21.0.2/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructor(DynamicHub.java:2930)
        at org.apache.kafka.common.utils.Utils.newInstance(Utils.java:397)
        ... 39 common frames omitted


Show some code:

Here is the snippet for the configuration:
    @Bean
    public KafkaSender<String, Log> kafkaSender(final MeterRegistry meterRegistry, final ObservationRegistry observationRegistry) {
        final Map<String, Object> properties = new HashMap<>();
        properties.put(SSL_PROTOCOL, SSL_VALUE);
        properties.put(SslConfigs.SSL_KEYSTORE_LOCATION_CONFIG, keyStoreLocation);
        properties.put(SslConfigs.SSL_KEYSTORE_PASSWORD_CONFIG, keyStorePassphrase);
        properties.put(SslConfigs.SSL_TRUSTSTORE_LOCATION_CONFIG, trustStoreLocation);
        properties.put(SslConfigs.SSL_TRUSTSTORE_PASSWORD_CONFIG, trustStorePassphrase);
        properties.put(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, bootstrapServer);
        properties.put(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringSerializer.class);
        properties.put(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaJsonSerializer.class);
        final SenderOptions<String, Log> senderOptions = SenderOptions.create(properties);
        return KafkaSender.create(senderOptions
                .producerListener(new MicrometerProducerListener(meterRegistry))
                .withObservation(observationRegistry));
    }


Question:

It seems one needs to manipulate registrars, some config.json to fix graalVM related issue.
What is needed in order to fix this issue?

Are you sure the config is correct? Spring has KafkaJsonSerializer, not Confluent... Confluent has Jsonschema serializer

agree with you, this is why I am very puzzled. This stack trace is quite confusing

Please share where you are configuring the serializer. You can see from the docs, that class doesn't exist https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/schema-registry/fundamentals/serdes-develop/index.html#supported-formats

Of course, updated with the producer configuration. And we are indeed actually using the KafkaJsonSerializer from confluent, and not from spring-kafka

Hmm. I guess if you're using the class directly and not passing a string to the properties, it must be valid. But I'm still curious what happens when you try the spring one? I'm not sure why graal would remove / exclude a default constructor

So, you are correct. If I swap the whole thing from confluence one to spring-kafka one, it works. So, somehow, you are correct and resolved the issue. But our teams requires to use confluence, therefore, I am still hoping to get a solution

They should work the same way for plain JSON. The Confluent ones generally are only useful when used with their Schema Registry. You can find a similar error to yours here, by the way. Maybe configure allDeclaredConstructors https://stackoverflow.com/a/57997082/2308683

It is working. If you would like to add this as answer, I ll accept. I am now having to carry this file unfortunately, [
{
"name": "io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaJsonSerializer",
"allDeclaredConstructors": true
}
]

Kafka uses reflection to lookup various classes from the properties, such as serializers.
You'll need to define a config file to enable certain reflection calls such as to get constructors
[ 
  { 
    "name": "io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaJsonSerializer", 
    "allDeclaredConstructors": true
  } 
]

